# Regex: Match 'in' operator in JavaScript source code

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to do a very simple static analysis on JavaScript source codes in C#. I want to create a regular expression which can match and replace the usage of 'in' operator in the source code.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

I had success with this however I need to exclude cases where the 'in' operator is used in a 'for' loop.

So for this example code:

```
const oneVariable = 'property' in myObject;
var trees = ['redwood', 'bay', 'cedar', 'oak', 'maple'];
const anotherVariable = 0 in trees;
const newVariable = variableName in myObject;
const newerVariable = (otherVarName in myObject);

console.log(whateverVariable in document);

for (var property1 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}

for (const property2 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}

for (let property3 in object1) {
  string1 += object1[property1];
}
```

I want to match these:

- 'property' in myObject
- 0 in trees
- variableName in myObject
- otherVarName in myObject
- whateverVariable in document

But not match these, because of the for() block and regardless of var/const/let keyword:

- property1 in object1
- property2 in object1
- property3 in object1

What is the correct regular expression to achieve this in C#?

Comment: What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// input is your Javascript code    
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<!(?:for\s?\()(?:.*)?)(\'?\w+\'?\sin\s\w+)");

var matchedInStatements = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
```

`matchedInStatements` now holds a all of your matches as strings.

For an explanation, check out [this](https://regex101.com/r/r0s8Gp/4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer however I dont want to match the = sign and also need to match the in operator in parenthesis like `const newVariable = (variableName in myObject);` I updated my question to include these as well, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @brnbs I updated my answer with what i think you're trying to achieve.

Comment: No, I want to match three words if the middle one is 'in', the left one is a string or a variable name and the right one is a variable name. I dont want to match if its placed in a for() block, but its not necessary to place after an equals sign. I have added more example to my question, I hope it helps.

Comment: @brnbs I updated my answer, which now fulfills all your **current** requirements. Please mark it as the answer. If it still isn't to your liking please make a new question.

Comment: Its perfect! Thanks for your time!